# How to group record in form?

Tags: forms, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I have in my *Grid* al lot record, If I want to display with group By for example for ItemId.

In the *init*

```
QueryBuildDataSource    qbds;
Query                                   query;
;
super();
query = new Query();
qbds = query.addDataSource(tablenum(InventTable));
```

How should I do to group by Item?

Comment: Have you tried searching what others have done? If you search "groupby" in "init" methods starting at AOT forms node you will get hundreds  of hits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
qbds.addgroubyField(fieldnum(InventTable,ItemId));
```